# Favicon going back to default when opening a new window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have changed my asp.net website favicon and it works perfectly when navigating through website's pages.

I have put the favicon.png in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/images/favicon.png" />
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

However when I open a image in new window my favicon changes back to the asp.net default icon.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <a href="~/images/holiday/sunset_1.png" target="_blank">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="~/images/holiday/sunset_1.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to change this or why it happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at a favicon generator if for no other reason than to check the output. You can typically specify multiple different types and sizes of favicons for better compatibility with different browsers and devices. You might need an .ico instead like Element.CR was mentioning. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reference your **favicon.ico** in your  section within the index of your site.

Sometimes, favicon(.png/.jpg) bug out depending on the browser you are using as well, where **.ico** is a common standard.

Comment: The reference is correct: in fact all webpages display favicon correctly, and no, it isn't a browser issue, all browsers have the same behavior...

Comment: Thanks! I recently read some article over the favicon.ico vs .png, I guess it doesn't matter but there was some argument over .ico being preferred. Odds are, I'm wrong, but just trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: in Visual Studio, right click on the project and select properties. Then navigate in Application -> Resources -> Icon and Manifest. Set the icon path.

Now it works also opening the images in new window (or tab).